# What does the phrase "fence building" mean?

Tags: expressions, phrase-meaning

What does the English phrase "fence building" mean?

Ex. usage: "You're gonna have to do some fence building.", which, from the context I heard it in (relationships between friends), seems to have the sense that of "repairing wrongs one has done to another." Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase has an evolving history. Its origins lie in the idiom "good fences make good neighbors", which is to say when you draw the lines in a relationship clearly then the involved parties are less likely to accidentally violate the expected rules.

This is still a pretty common idiom, however, "mending fences" or its derivative "fence building" has a somewhat different meaning. These expressions rather mean repairing broken relationships. This may be by re-establishing boundaries, but not necessarily, it specifically means re-establishing the relationship.

The idiom is a little misleading, what you are rebuilding is the relationship rather than the tool that facilitated the relationship, however idioms and etymology are not an exact science.

See this interesting article:

[Mending Fences](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/mend-fences.html)

Here is Wiktionary on the phrase itself.

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mend_fences)

Comment: Yes, that's correct; relationships between people was also part of the context I heard it in.